# Custom datadog check does not provide full output from subprocess command ouput

Tags: python-3.x, windows, datadog

## The Problem

I am currently writing a Custom Datadog check on one of our Windows license servers in an attempt to parse the output of a local status command. The issue I am running into is the `output` from the `get_subprocess_output` command seems to be getting cut short.

For instance

```
status, output, retcode = get_subprocess_output(
            ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\tlm_server-win32-x86-2.6.0\\bin\\tlm_server.exe", "-s"],
            self.log,
            raise_on_empty_output=True,
            log_debug=True
        )

        print(output)
```

is the relevant piece of code I've used to see what `output` contains.

When I run

```
.\agent.exe check license_check
```

to test my custom check, I get the following output:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Datadog\Datadog Agent\bin> .\agent.exe check license_check
asking for status, localhost, 5436


=========
Collector
=========

  Running Checks
  ==============

    license_check (1.0.0)
    ------------------
      Instance ID: my_license_server:
      Configuration Source: file:C:\ProgramData\Datadog\conf.d\license_check.d\conf.yaml
      Total Runs: 1
      Metric Samples: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Events: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Service Checks: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Average Execution Time : 109ms
      Last Execution Date : 2023-07-11 18:17:22 PDT / 2023-07-12 01:17:22 UTC (1689124642000)
      Last Successful Execution Date : 2023-07-11 18:17:22 PDT / 2023-07-12 01:17:22 UTC (1689124642000)
```

### The part that is of interest to me is:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Datadog\Datadog Agent\bin> .\agent.exe check license_check
asking for status, localhost, 5436
```

after the command is run, there should be more output following this line.

The expected output should look something along the line of

```
asking for status, localhost, 5436

RESPONSE: tlm_server running on host 'my_license_server' port 5436
Version: 2.6.0

License 1: fake_license *.*.* :: 10 in use, 133 available, 143 total, maint expires 20-Jan-2025
     -> me@10.167.123.184 checked out at Mon Jun 12 12:52:47 2023
```

## What I tried

I opened up an interactive python shell and confirmed that using `subprocess` instead of using the Datadog `get_subprocess_output`:

```
>>> result = subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\tlm_server-win32-x86-2.6.0\\bin\\tlm_server.exe","-s"], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
>>> print(result)
```

did provide me the expected output with no truncating.

I've actually done this exact same custom check before on another/different Windows license server and didnt run into this weird issue. I'm really unsure of where to go next with this. Any suggestions?